# Strange error when build Phonegap showing Manifest merger failed

Tags: android, xml, cordova

I use Phonegap version 5.0.0-0.28.1 and Android 5.1.1 API 22 (SDK Platform), also use latest Android SDK Build-tools (22.0.1).

I configure my path ANDROID_HOME set in works path, so this isn't issue anymore. After create and add platform in android, the problem show when I build source:

> $ phonegap build android --release

Show error:

> Execution failed for task ':processDebugManifest'.
>
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 7 cannot be smaller than version 10 declared in library /Users/myname/lalaland/platforms/android/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/android/CordovaLib/unspecified/debug/AndroidManifest.xml

I assume AndroidManifest.xml in android must set in *** android:minSdkVersion="10" *** because default xml put min SDK version in 7. So I edited the AndroidManifest.xml turn 7 to 10, but still showing error. When I use build also monitoring the script using Textwrangler, XML script always turn back to default when min SDK version set in 7.

Please help, kindly share if you have same experience like me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look in config.xml "preference", try to change the value for minSdkVersion.

Example: `<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="10" />`

Comment: Markup (like the XML fragment you were trying to put in your answer) must be formatted as inline code using backticks ``, or as code block adding 4 spaces at the beginning of each line, otherwise it is not visible (I suggested an edit to you answer, doing exactly this). See also the [editing help page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).